# Mysql Triggers, declare a variable and use it as column name

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the table "mytable" that contains the "columnname" field wich is the name of a column in mytable2.

I use this one for the selection:

```
SET @DptScn = (SELECT columnname FROM mytable WHERE tablename = 'CustomTableName' AND fieldlabel = 'CustomField');
SET @identifiedid=144;
```

but, when I try:

```
SELECT @DptScn FROM mytable2 WHERE identifiedid = @identifiedid;
```

this give me NOT the content of the field but the name containted into variable @DptScn...

Any advice?
I can't use Prepared Statement because I'm in a Trigger...

UPDATE:

As suggested by spencer7593 I'm creating a procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_t;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p_t (IN DptTcn VARCHAR(255), IN tid INT, OUT tT INT)
BEGIN
    SET @DptTcn = DptTcn;
    SET @tid = tid;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT @DptTcn FROM mytable3 WHERE tid = @tid');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I try it:

```
SET @DptTcn = (SELECT columnname mytable WHERE tablename = 'CustomTableName' AND fieldlabel = 'CustomField');
SET @identifiedid=145;
CALL proc_ticket(@DptTcn, @identifiedid, @DptT);
```

But I receive a:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Comment: Nope. No way without prepared statements.

Comment: `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@DptTcn,' FROM mytable3 WHERE tid = ',@tid);` That's how you would need to construct a SQL statement; the SQL text in your procedure is not valid; it is not valid to use MySQL user variables in place of identifiers (e.g. column names) in a SQL statement.

Comment: I changed that but the problem's still there (Commands out of sync)

Comment: It looks like you are missing the FROM keyword in your query...  ` = (SELECT columnname *FROM* mytable WHERE`.  I provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to consider is creating a `PROCEDURE` that makes use of prepared statements, and then calling the the stored procedure from the trigger.

The SQL statement you execute to get the value from a particular column MUST have the column_name specified in the SQL text; this can't be derived "dynamically" in the execution of the statement.

To achieve something like this, you'll need to run two separate statements; one to get the column_name; the second to "`SELECT column_name FROM`". And the MySQL provided mechanism for executing that second query is a prepared statement.

---

**Followup**

Here's an example. I tried to get this built in SQLFiddle, but wasn't able to get it working (it just hung.  So, here's the output from a mysql command line client instead.

(All of the statements below use the same delimiter `//` because we can't use a semicolon as a delimiter for the stored procedure. In SQLFiddle, we have to use the same delimiter on all statements, and the `//` just happens to be one of the options in SQLFiddle.)

```
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE foo(IN colname VARCHAR(255), IN id INT, OUT val VARCHAR(255))
    -> BEGIN
    ->    -- handler for "Unknown column" and "No data" exceptions
    ->    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1054, 1329 BEGIN SET val = NULL; END;
    ->    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',colname,' INTO @val FROM t WHERE id = ',id,' LIMIT 1');
    ->    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    ->    EXECUTE stmt;
    ->    SET val = @val;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t (id INT, attr VARCHAR(4), ball VARCHAR(4))//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'abcd','efgh'),(2,'ijkl','mnop')//
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CALL foo('attr',1,@attr_1)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL foo('attr',2,@attr_2)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL foo('ball',1,@ball_1)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL foo('ball',2,@ball_2)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL foo('attr',777,@err_bad_id)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL foo('badcol',1,@err_badcol)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @attr_1
    ->      , @attr_2
    ->      , @ball_1
    ->      , @ball_2
    ->      , @err_bad_id
    ->      , @err_badcol//
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| @attr_1 | @attr_2 | @ball_1 | @ball_2 | @err_bad_id | @err_badcol |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| abcd    | ijkl    | efgh    | mnop    | NULL        | NULL        |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I updated the answer following your suggestion... but there's something that I don't understand...

Comment: @MiPnamic: I couldn't get this to build in SQL Fiddle (it just hangs, saying "Building"), so I pasted into here the output from a mysql command line client.  Note the SQL statement is formulated as a string; the string that gets executed has only a single user variable, and that's the one the SQL statement assigns a value to. The procedure also includes exception handlers for the "No data" exception (raised when the query doesn't return a row), and the "Unknown column" exception (raised when the specified column doesn't exist in the table). You may want to handle exceptions a different way.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a SP and give the column name.

```
create proc dbo.TestGetData(@DptScn nvarchar(256))
as
  begin
    set nocount on
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @DptScn FROM mytable2 WHERE identifiedid = 144'
    exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DptScn nvarchar(256)', @DptScn =@DptScn 
end
```

Then

```
exec dbo.TestGetData 'Column1'
```

Comment: can I "exec dbo.TestGetData @DptScn" in my trigger?

Comment: This syntax is for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.